# Why terminal command doesn't use hosts IP in /etc/hosts in MacOS?

Tags: git, macos, dns, macos-sierra, hosts

I have already add DNS IP to /etc/hosts:
$ cat /etc/hosts |grep -is googlesource

```
216.58.200.33   android.googlesource.com
216.58.200.33   android-review.googlesource.com
216.58.200.33   fuchsia.googlesource.com
216.58.200.33   googlesource.com
216.58.200.33   boringssl.googlesource.com
216.58.200.33   gerrit.googlesource.com
216.58.200.33   gerrit-review.googlesource.com
216.58.200.33   chromium.googlesource.com
216.58.200.33   kernel.googlesource.com
216.58.200.33   gwt.googlesource.com
216.58.200.33   code.googlesource.com
216.58.200.33   www.googlesource.com
216.58.200.33   go.googlesource.com
216.58.200.33   go-review.googlesource.com
216.58.200.33   cdn.googlesource.com
```

but when I ping googlesource.com, it also use IP 74.125.204.82:

```
$ ping googlesource.com
PING googlesource.com (74.125.204.82): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
Request timeout for icmp_seq 6
Request timeout for icmp_seq 7
Request timeout for icmp_seq 8
^C
--- googlesource.com ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

and I use git to clone source code from googlesource.com, it still failed:

```
$ git clone https://skia.googlesource.com/skia.git
Cloning into 'skia'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://skia.googlesource.com/skia.git/': Failed to connect to skia.googlesource.com port 443: Operation timed out
```

Why?
How to force git use IP in /etc/hosts to resolve URL?

Comment: Make sure the entries you added are properly formatted: IP address followed by a space or tab, followed by the name, then a linefeed at the end of the line. Try printing the hosts file with cat -vet /etc/hosts to make normally invisible characters visible. Each line should look like "216.58.200.33^Igooglesource.com$" (the "^I" is a tab, and the "$" is the linefeed) or "216.58.200.33 googlesource.com$". If you see a "^M" (carriage return) just before the "$", you have DOS/Windows formatted text and you need to remove the carriage return(s).

Answer (score 0):

`sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` required?
(Source: https://www.imore.com/how-edit-your-macs-hosts-file-and-why-you-would-want )